# 405 Not allowed error on BAN or PURGE requests against varnish

Tags: docker, varnish, varnish-vcl, lando

I'm trying to set up varnish as part of my lando (docker)-based development installation. It consists of 2 containers:

- `appserver`, running Apache + PHP-FPM
- `varnish`

Somehow, I fail to set up a correct VCL configuration file, resulting in fails like this, when BAN requests are made against the varnish from the appserver container:

```
BAN http:\/\/varnish\/` resulted in a `405 Not allowed from 172.29.0.3
```

This is happening with the following VCL rule:

```
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "appserver";
    "127.0.0.1";
    "::1";
    "0.0.0.0/0";
    "128.0.0.0/1";
    "172.0.0.0/8";
}
```

I can ping from inside `varnish` container to `appserver` without any problem.

How can I fix my config, please? Please let me know, if my question is missing some info.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it. You have to allow an UNRESTRICTED PURGE or add X-VC-Purge-Key to header and assign a value to it. Here is my lando configuration :

```html
services:
  varnish:
    type: varnish:6.0
    backends:
      - appserver
    backend_port: 80
    overrides:
      environment:
        VARNISH_SECRET: secret
        VARNISH_ALLOW_UNRESTRICTED_PURGE: 1
```

Comment: Ping me if you still have a problem with that.